# pricebook lookup field is not autopopulating

Tags: opportunity, pricebook, customization, order, merge-field

I have a opportunity object and a pricebook lookup field on that object. I have a create order button on opportunity object when I clicked the button the detail page should be open and pricbook lookup field should be autopopulated. I wrote the javascipt code on that button when I am writing `{!opportunity.pricebook2.name}` to fetch the value. Error:

> The merge field is not found

The pricebook2 is not showing in insert field option. kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

`{!opportunity.pricebook2.name}` Could be breaking due to the VLookup being in lowercase.

Try matching the API case formatting like : `{!Opportunity.Pricebook2.Name}`. Formula lookups work in the second format. If not - we may need to see code in order to help more

Comment: Not working Error Error: Field Opportunity.Pricebook2.Name does not exist. Check spelling.

Comment: @amit Other than permission errors, or if you're working advanced currency. Could we get a code sample on your original post? It might be able to help out some more